# How to use Ajax with express.render()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm not getting that....

Usually to render my users.html page I do

```
// in index.html

<a href="/users">Users Page</a>


// server side using express

router.get('/users', function (req, res) { res.render('users'); });
```

But if I use Axios to make the request

```
<a onclick="axios.get(`users`)">Users Page</a>
```

Express get the request correctly but the browser never loads the users.html page

My reason to do that way its because I want to check authorization header before loads a new page of my app. And my Axios defaults already have this information.

Comment: You need to understand that `axios.get(`users`)` makes AJAX request. This is not the same as reloading page what happens when you click `a` href.

Comment: Ok @dfsq! So, how could I send auth info without ajax? To the server check auth of the user before render the new page

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works!
If you have something like this:

```
<a onclick="axios.get('users').then(res => document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = res.data">Users Page</a>
```

The 'somediv' will load all the HTML rendered by express.

So you can use it to load some parts of the actual page.

Its possible to do `document.write(res.data);` but this will not change the document.location neither will load the scripts of the new page.